# Stuck in a Clojure loop, need some guidance

Tags: loops, if-statement, clojure, lisp

I am stuck in a Clojure loop and need help to get out.

I first want to define a vector

```
(def lawl [1 2 3 4 5])
```

I do

```
(get lawl 0)
```

And get "1" in return. Now, I want a loop that get each number in the vector, so I do:

```
(loop [i 0]
   (if (< i (count lawl)) 
     (get lawl i) 
       (recur (inc i))))
```

In my mind this is supposed to set the value of i to nil, then if i is lower then the count of the lawl vector, it should get each lawl value and then increase the i variable with 1 and try again, getting the next value in the vector.

However, this does not work and I have spent some time trying to get it working and are totally stuck, would appreciate some help. I have also tried changing "if" to "when" with the same result, it doesn't provide any data the REPL just enters a new line and blink.

EDIT: Fixed the recur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to consider what is "to get each `lawl` value" supposed to mean. Your `get` call does indeed "get" the appropriate value, but since you never do anything with it, it is simply discarded; Bozhidar's suggestion to add a `println` is a good one and will allow you to see that the loop does indeed access all the elements of `lawl` (just replace `(get ...)` with `(println (get ...))`, after fixing the `(inc)` => `(inc i)` thing Bozhidar mentioned also).

That said, if you simply want to do something with each number in turn, `loop` / `recur` is not a good way to go about it at all. Here are some others:

```
;;; do some side-effecty thing to each number in turn:
(dotimes [i (count lawl)]
  (println (str i ": " (lawl i)))) ; you don't really need the get either

;; doseq is more general than dotimes, but doesn't give you equally immediate
;; acess to the index
(doseq [n lawl]
  (println n))

;;; transform the lawl vector somehow and return the result:
; produce a seq of the elements of lawl transformed by some function
(map inc lawl)
; or if you want the result to be a vector too...
(vec (map inc lawl))
; produce a seq of the even members of lawl multiplied by 3
(for [n lawl
      :when (even? n)]
  (* n 3))
```

This is just the beginning. For a good tour around Clojure's standard library, see the [Clojure -- Functional Programming for the JVM](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/clojure/article.html) article by Mark Volkmann.

Comment: If you replace `inc` with, say, `produce-html` in the `map` examples, you'll likely get the best fit for your use case.

Answer (score 3):

`(recur (inc))` should be `(recur (inc i))`

Even so this code will just return 1 in the end, if you want a listing of the number you might add a print expression :-) Btw index based loops are not needed at all in scenarios such as this.

```
(loop [list [1 2 3 4 5] ]
         (if (empty? list)
             (println "done")
             (do
              (println (first list))
              (recur (rest list)))))
```

Comment: The problem is that I have an external vector which I need each value to be "pushed" to a function. The example I used above is just a way of showing how I try to get each value in the "lawl" vector to be pushed to the "get" function. I have a function that generates a HTML output, and I have a function that reads a file and sends it to the HTML function for generation. I have created a function that puts each file in a given directory in a vector, so I am trying to make a loop that push each file into the function.

Comment: Lets say I have vector "dirs" which containts ["/home/bozhidar/file1" "/home/bozhidar/file"] I want a loop that sends each of those files to a function. What a for-loop would do in C or Python.

Comment: You have to ask yourself what does sending a file to your function mean to you. If you have a function which takes a filename and *returns* some HTML, you'll want to do `(map produce-html the-files)` (where `the-files` may be any seqable, in particular a vector). If you have a function which takes a filename and *causes a side effect involving the HTML*, you'll want to do something like `(doseq [f the-files] (print-html f))`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm about 10-1/2 years too late on this, but here goes:

The problem here is a pretty common misunderstanding of how the arguments to the `if` function are used. `if` takes three arguments - the `condition/predicate`, the code to be executed if the predicate is true, and the code to be executed if the predicate is false. In this case both of the true and false cases are supplied. Perhaps if we fix the indentation and add some appropriate comments we'll be able to see what's happening more easily:

```
(loop [i 0]
  (if (< i (count lawl)) 
    (get lawl i)       ; then 
    (recur (inc i))))  ; else
```

So the problem is not that the code gets "stuck" in the loop - the problem is that the `recur` form is never executed. Here's how the execution flows:

1. The `loop` form is entered; `i` is set to 0.
2. The `if` form is entered.
3. The predicate form is executed and found to be true.
4. The code for the `then` branch of the `if` is executed, returning 1.
5. Execution then falls out the bottom of the `loop` form.

Right now I hear people screaming "Wait! WHAT?!?". Yep - in an `if` form you can only have a single form in the "then" and "else" branches. "But...THAT'S STUPID!" I hear you say. Well...not really. You just need to know how to work with it. There's a way to group multiple forms together in Clojure into a single form, and that's done by using `do`. If we want to group `(get lawl i)` and `(recur...` together we could write it as

```
(loop [i 0]
  (if (< i (count lawl)) 
    (do
      (get lawl i)       ; then 
      (recur (inc i))
    )
  )
)
```

As you can see, we have no "else" branch on this `if` form - instead, the `(get...` and `(recur...` forms are grouped together by the `(do`, so they execute one after the other. So after recurring its way through the `lawl` vector the above snippet returns nil, which is kind of ugly. So let's have it return something more informative:

```
(loop [i 0]
  (if (< i (count lawl)) 
    (do
      (get lawl i)         ; then
      (recur (inc i)))
    (str "All done i=" i)  ; else
  )
)
```

Now our `else` branch returns "All done i=5".

Comment: Me from 10 years ago appreciate you dedication to answering old questions